# Getting and inserting AUTO INCREMENTED rows into an associative-table?

Tags: java, mysql, insert, auto-increment, associative-table

I have two inputs:

```
Basket Name:  <input type="text">
```

AND

```
Fruits<select name="fruits">
   // Some java code that populate my drop down list from a SELECT sql 
   // that is pulling from my database table called 'Fruits'
   // i.e. <option value='SELECT fruitID FROM fruits'> 'SELECT fruitName FROM fruits' </option>    
   ...
  </select>
```

And I want to do the following two SQL inserts at the same time when my `<form>` is submitted:

**SQL 1**:  Insert `'Basket Name'` into a table called `'Baskets'`;

**SQL 2**:  Insert the `'fruitID'` (i.e. `<option value = "01"> Apple </option>`) into an associative table called `'Baskets_Fruits'`

My table structures:

**BASKETS** table:

basketID -> AUTO_INCREMENT int(11), NOT NULL

basketName -> varchar(255)

**BASKETS_FRUITS** table:

basketID_FK -> foreign key of 'basketID' from Baskets table

fruitID_FK -> foreign key of 'fruitID' from Fruits table

**FRUITS** table:

fruitID_FK -> AUTO_INCREMENT int(11), NOT NULL

fruitName -> varchar(255)

How may I obtain the current `basketID_FK` if `basketID` that is referenced is **AUTO-INCREMENTED**?  I'm not quite sure how to code the SQL syntax for getting the value of an AUTO-INCREMENTED column.

**EDIT:**

Do I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO baskets_fruits (basketID_FK, fruitIDFK)
(SELECT baskets.basketID, fruits.fruitID FROM baskets, fruits
WHERE baskets.basketID = "Foo" AND fruits.fruitID = "BAR");
```

But what would the `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` syntax be like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work? This obviously would be after the insert, then you can manipulate whatever you would like after.

```
SELECT * FROM BASKETS
INNER JOIN BASKETS_FRUITS ON basketID = basketID_FK
WHERE basketName = 'whatever the basket name is'
```

This would give you the key based on a specific basketName where you can then find the fruitID_FK if needed.